# How to find a substring from a string using regular expression in php?

Tags: php, regex, string, expression

I have a string like "I love my country". If i search for 'country' my program will show "exist". But if I search 'count' my program will show "Not exist".

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: `print preg_match('#\bcountry\b#',"I love my country")?'exist':'Not exist';` rest is on you, read the artical about wordboundaries from @AbraCadaver

Comment: Why not use [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)?

Comment: in strpos if I give 'count' as value it shows me exist.

Comment: It would help to point out the expected result in the question, not only the erroneous one. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is [this](http://regexr.com/3fkq6) what you're looking for?

I'm not a master of Regex so someone may have a more optimal solution but simply searching for country with word boundaries should get you what you're after.

`/\b(country)\b/g`

So in PHP something like the following:

```
$string = 'I love my country';
$matchExists = preg_match('/\b(country)\b/', $string);

echo ($matchExists) ? 'Match Found' : 'No Match Found'; // Output: Match Found
```

And one that fails:

```
$string = 'I love mycountry';
$matchExists = preg_match('/\b(country)\b/', $string);

echo ($matchExists) ? 'Match Found' : 'No Match Found'; // Output: No Match Found
```

And reminder you can see a bunch of different outputs [here](http://regexr.com/3fkq6) as well as test any others you may have.